# I cannot update Ubuntu 64 11.10, have constant crashes

Tags: 11.10, firefox, updates

I can't seem to update,  try via update manager & get this message:

The package system is broken.
If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Now run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libc6: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.1 is installed
libc6:i386: Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.1 is installed
```

When manually entering command `apt-get install -f` I get the below message:

```
:~$ apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?'
```

I get loads of Firefox crashes & now simply when copying a file from one folder to another the system crashes, seems to be degenerating - clearly I'm not very techy (don't know what or where 3rd party repositories are or how to disable them..) need some help.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install -f`

Do not forget you need admin rights to update your system.

If all is lost a re-install might be an option. Save the important files to an usb stick or a cd and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute these commands. They will help to clear/fix broken packages/dependencies and also try to install required library packages needed:

```
1. Fix using Command Line:
    $ sudo apt-get autoremove
    $ sudo apt-get --purge remove
    $ sudo apt-get autoclean
    $ sudo apt-get clean
    $ sudo apt-get -f install
And then try to upgrade again:
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade

2. Fix using Synaptic Package Manager (preferred)
```

- Fist install synaptic package manager if you don't have already installed. You can install forcefully previous version of your packages:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install synaptic
  ```
- Then open synaptic package manager -> click **Custom Filters** down-left -> click **Broken** top-left, it will list all broken packages try to all broken packages. Also if any residual packages are there on more option you will get as **residual packages**.
- Search for packages first **libc-bin** then **libc6**, **one by one**, select it, chose **Package** from the menu -> **Force Version** and chose some previous version from the list. Then click **Apply** to install it.
- Try to upgrade again, if everything goes ok:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

Hope it works for you.